# Postgres. Could not open iTerm

Tags: sql, postgresql, app

Давно и без проблем работал Postgres.app
Но в один момент, при попытке зайти в любую базу, начало вылетать
     Could not open iTerm
     Make sure that Postgres.app has permission to automate iTerm.
     Alternatively, you can also just execute the following command 
     manually to connect to the database:
     /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/11/bin/psql -p5432 " 
     <НАЗВАНИЕ БАЗЫ>"

Незадолго до появления ошибки я менял пароль у одного из юзеров.

Comment: Вы решили проблему?